# Blazor cannot set style property

Tags: css, blazor, mudblazor, mudtextfield

cannot set the style property of an element it's always empty. When I write out `StyleString` it says `color: red`

[Transposed verbatim from the comment]

```cs
AT(StyleString = ShouldBeError ? "color: red" : "") 
</div>
 @StyleString 
<MudCard> 
  <MudCardHeader> 
    <CardHeaderContent> 
      <MudText Typo="Typo.h6" Style="AT($"{StyleString}")"> 
       //..... 

ATcode { 
//... 
private bool ShouldBeError; 
private string StyleString = ""; 
private List<Location> Data = new List<Location>();
```

[image]

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Rather than _describing_ your code, it would be better to _show_ your code with a [mre].

Comment: basically, it's the same as in the image

AT(StyleString = ShouldBeError ? "color: red" : "")
        </div>
        @StyleString
        <MudCard>
            <MudCardHeader>
                <CardHeaderContent>
                    <MudText Typo="Typo.h6" Style="AT($"{StyleString}")">

//.....

ATcode { //...
    private bool ShouldBeError;

    private string StyleString = "";

    private List<Location> Data = new List<Location>();

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a MudBlazor user, so here's a very simple example demonstrating how to set properties on any element/component.  In this case the class of the button rather than the style on a component.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div class="m-2">
    <button class="@_btnCss" @onclick="this.Change">
        Switch
    </button>
</div>

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

@code {
    private bool _enabled;
    private string _btnCss => _enabled ? "btn btn-success" : "btn  btn-secondary";

    private void Change()
        => _enabled = !_enabled;
}
```

[Personal] Note that I try to keep component logic out of the markup whenever I can.  I think it's easier to read.

Comment: true, the problem is that MudText isn't styling and I still don't have any idea why.

Answer (score 0):

I put a div above MudText and it worked straight away.

Answer (score 0):

In **MudBlazor** you need to use `theme Colors` or `Palette colors` Like:

`Color.Primary`, `Color.Secondary` ...ets

for more, see [this link](https://www.mudblazor.com/customization/default-theme#palette)

```
<MudText Typo="Typo.h6" Color="@(ShouldBeError ? Color.Primary : Color.Secondary)" > Some text </MudText>

@code {
    private bool ShouldBeError = true; 
}
```